# Lemma 12 in Robin's paper

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

How to show that $$\frac{\pi(x)\log (\theta(x)) }{\theta(x)}\leq 1+ \frac{1}{\log (\theta(x)}+(1+ \frac{2...}{\log^2 (\theta(x))})$$ with the formula  $$\pi(x) \leq \frac{\theta(x)}{\log (x)}+ \frac{x}{\log^2(x)}(1+ \frac{2.843}{\log (x)})$$ in Lemma 12 of G. Robin's paper 'Estimation de la fonction ..'?

Comment: Please further fix your math expression.

Comment: I told you that it doesn't quite make sense. Start from  an effective version of the PNT: $|\theta(x)-x|\le C x/\log^2 x, |\pi(x)-x/\log-x/\log^2 x|\le A x/\log^3 x$, then you get both your formulas. Robin's paper assumes that you know how to prove the PNT as well as the effective bound $|\theta(x)-x|\le B x^{1/2}\log^2 x$ which is equivalent to the RH.

Comment: Using $\mid\theta(x)-x\mid \leq\frac{cx}{\log^2(x)}$, it's easy to show formula (37), but formula (36) is asymptotically true, but difficult  explicitly

Answer (score 0):

We have $\frac{\pi(x)}{\theta(x)}\leq \frac{1}{\log x}+ \frac{1}{\theta(x)}\frac{x}{\log^2 x}(1+ \frac{2.843}{\log x})$, now invoking the increase of $\frac{x}{\log^2 x}(1+ \frac{2.843}{\log x})$ and  $x\leq\frac{\theta}{f(x)}$ with $f(x)\leq1$, we obtain
$\frac{\pi(x)}{\theta(x)}\leq \frac{1}{\log x}+ \frac{1}{f(x)}\frac{1}{\log^2 (\frac{\theta}{f(x)})}(1+ \frac{2.843}{\log (\frac{\theta}{f(x)})})$, it's no more than
$\frac{\pi(x)}{\theta(x)}\leq \frac{1}{\log x}+ \frac{1}{f(x)}\frac{1}{\log^2 (\theta(x))}(1+ \frac{2.843}{\log (\theta(x))})$, so
$\frac{\pi(x)\log (\theta(x)) }{\theta(x)}\leq \frac{\log (\theta(x))}{\log x}+ \frac{1}{f(x)}\frac{1}{\log (\theta(x))}(1+ \frac{2.843}{\log (\theta(x))})$???